# Getting Invalid Lambda response for Amazon lex

Tags: aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-chatbot

I am trying to build a chatbot using Lex but I have hit a roadblock and I am stuck here since two days.

When I am tesing in lambda function it works fine with test events but when testing it in lex getting error as below:

[lex console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAQDk.png)

This is how I am calling from lambda function:

[lambda function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTSkB.png)

Any help what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not post images of code or errors. Always post them as text, [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can edit your original question and update it with the relevant information. Please also read the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Answer (score 0):

The format of your response is incorrect. Please check the below sample for how it should look: -

```
return{
        "dialogAction": {
            "type": "Close",
            "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
            "message": {
                "contentType": "PlainText",
                "content": "My text here"
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, refer to the AWS Lex documentation for a full view of the input and output formats.
[AWS Lex Input Event and Response Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-response-format)